# How to initialize Meta class 'model' variable in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

This may be a Django or a general python question.  I have a ModelForm.  Based on a user input I need to make use of one model or the other.  For example, if the input is 'M', I need to associate he form with MaleTable otherwise with FemaleTable.  I can create 2 ModelForms

```
class DemographicM (ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MaleTable

class DemographicF (ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = FemaleTable
```

but, I would like to use just one ModelForm and initialize it with the right model based on input.

I understand that Meta is just an inner class.  How can I initialize the 'model' variable at the time of the form creation?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest keeping them both and using them like this in view

```
if choice == 'M':
    TableForm = DemographicM
else:
    TableForm = DemographicF

form = TableForm()
```

Comment: I was trying to see if I can avoid creating both forms, since the only difference (between he forms) is the model

Answer (score 0):

For a metaclass its instance is a class itself. So, the solution would be to create the class on the go using a function. Something like the following will work:

```
MODEL = None
def define_meta_attributes(model):
  global MODEL
  MODEL = model
def make_form_class(*args, **kwargs):
  class Demographic (ModelForm):
    class Meta:
      model = MODEL
  return Demographic(*args, **kwargs)
```

Now, all you will have to do is call define_meta_attributes first with the desired model and then make_form_class like so:

```
define_meta_attributes(MaleTable)
MaleTableForm = make_form_class()
```